# Initializing object (ex. Textview) on a widget activity

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I have made an Android application that shows an IP address, and the name of the Wi-Fi and other things, (all using an asynchronously task). Now, I'm making its widget.

Here the code:

```
package com.example.utente.network;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.format.Formatter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class NetWidget extends AppWidgetProvider implements asyncTask.ITask{

    static void updateAppWidget(final Context context,
                                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        TextView ipv4;
        TextView infowifi;

        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.net_widget);

        ipv4 = (TextView)views     ********HOT TO INITIALIZE??

        // Setto tutti gli elemnti del widget con eventuali valori di default
        final  WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        // asyncTask runner = new asyncTask(getApplicationContext());
        asyncTask runner = new asyncTask(context.getApplicationContext());
        runner.execute();

        final WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
        final int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
        final String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
        String nomewifi =(wifiInfo.getSSID());

        Log.d("Widget_IP", "doInBackground: " +  ipAddress);
        Log.d("widget_nome_wifi", "doInBackground: " +  nomewifi);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate( final Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.d("UPDATE WIDGET", "onUpdate: ");

        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressValue(int aValue, Integer value) {

    }
}
```

In this widget, there are two text views (for the moment), but how can I set  their text with the IP address and the Wi-Fi name (that I have from my asynchronously task)? I don't know how to initialize the text view. I supposed it should be like a normal act:

```
TextView  myTextView;
myTextView = (textView)findViewById(R.id.mytextViewID);
```

But evidently it isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialise the TextView directly. Instead, you can use RemoteView to update the TextView. So, for example:

```
views.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view_id, "Text to set");
```

Then, once you call "updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)", the TextView will update.